Compliance with Google Knowledge Graph API Terms When Caching Responses for Machine Learning
I'm developing an application that queries Google's Knowledge Graph API and stores the responses in a database for caching purposes. These cached responses will subsequently used in a prompt to classify business records.
Before proceeding further, I want to ensure that my approach is compliant with Google's Terms of Service for their Knowledge Graph API. I have a few concerns:

Are there any specific restrictions regarding the caching of API responses that I should be aware of?
Does using these cached responses in machine learning models potentially violate any terms?
Are there particular data privacy or attribution requirements that I must adhere to?
What are the general guidelines or best practices when using such API data for training machine learning models?

I have read their Developer terms and Places API terms but am still uncertain.
Any guidance or insights into potential areas of non-compliance and how to address them would be greatly appreciated. If you can point out specific sections of the Google terms, share experiences with similar projects, or highlight best practice guides that would be very helpful.
